# How to copy a row (variable) and paste it into a specific cell (also row as variable) with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, cell, copy-paste

I'm learning VBA and I want to shorten a code I've written.
I want to copy a row which is a variable and paste it to the row above and then the second column. Ideally, it also pastes together row (-1,2) and (2,1) as it is a broken row in Excel.

I now have the following code:

```
Sub Clean()

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

For i = 2 To 48987

x = i - 1

If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) = True Then

'Do nothing

Else

    Cells(x, 2) = Cells(x, 2) + Cells(i, 1)
    Cells(x, 3) = Cells(i, 2)
    Cells(x, 4) = Cells(i, 3)
    Cells(x, 5) = Cells(i, 4)
    Cells(x, 6) = Cells(i, 5)
    Cells(x, 7) = Cells(i, 6)
    Cells(x, 8) = Cells(i, 7)
    Cells(x, 9) = Cells(i, 8)
    Cells(x, 10) = Cells(i, 9)
    Cells(x, 11) = Cells(i, 10)
    Cells(x, 12) = Cells(i, 11)
    Cells(x, 13) = Cells(i, 12)
    Cells(x, 14) = Cells(i, 13)
    Cells(x, 15) = Cells(i, 14)
    Cells(x, 16) = Cells(i, 15)
    Rows(i).Delete
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would like to shorten the repetitive `Cells(x, 3) = Cells(i, 2)` bit. This can be easily done by leaving the first calculation adding the first cell to the second, and copying the rest of the line like so:

```
Sub Clean2()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 48987

If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) = True Then

    Cells(i - 1, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) + Cells(i, 1)
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 15)).Copy Range(Cells(i - 1, 3), Cells(i - 1, 16))
    Rows(i).Delete

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Please note there is no need to have variable `x`, as `i-1` works just as well, and negates the need for anyone who reads your code to look up what variable `x` does. But this might be a personal preference.

Alternatively you could add another loop instead, but this might not be as fast (untested)

```
    For j = 2 To 15
        Cells(i - 1, j + 1) = Cells(i, j)
    Next j
```